# Check for existence of multiple fields in MongoDB document

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to query a database collection that holds documents of processes for those documents that have specific fields. For simplicity imagine the following general document schema:

```
{
    "timestamp": ISODate("..."),
    "result1": "pass",
    "result2": "fail"
}
```

Now, when a process is started a new document is inserted with only the timestamp. When that process reaches certain stages the fields `result1` and `result2` are added over time. Some processes however do not reach the stages `1` or `2` and therefore have no result fields.

I would like to query the database to retrieve only those documents, which have BOTH `result1` and `result2`.

I am aware of the [$exists](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/#op._S_exists) operator, but as far as I can tell this only works for one field at a time, i.e. `db.coll.find({"result1": {$exists: true}})`. The `$exists` operator cannot be used as a top level operator. E.g. this does **not** work:

> `db.coll.find({"$exists": {"result1": true, "result2": true}})`

To check for both results I would need:

> `db.coll.find({"result1": {"$exists": true}, "result2": {"$exists": true}})`

Now that already becomes tedious for more than one variable.

Is there a better way to do this?
(Also, I am doing this in Python, so if there is a solution for just the pymongo driver that would make me happy already.)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43898220/pymongo-aggregate-filter-by-count-of-fields-number-dynamic for aggregation (server side) solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about better, but you can always process with JavaScript via [**`$where`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/):

```python
jsStr = """var doc = this;
           return ['result1','result2','result3']
           .every(function(key) { 
               return doc.hasOwnProperty(key) 
           });"""

coll.find({ "$where": jsStr })
```

But you are going to have to specify an array of "keys" to check for somewhere.

If you think you have a lot of keys to type out, then why not just "build" your query expression:

```python
whitelist = [ "result1", "result2", "result3" ]
query = {}

for key in whitelist:
    query[key] = { "$exists": True }

coll.find(query)
```

That saves a bit of typing and since all MongoDB queries are just data structures anyway then using basic data manipulation to build queries makes sense.

Comment: Thanks. This works well and is exactly what I ended up doing in the meantime. In your for loop I think you want to have: query[key] = ...

Answer (score 1):

How about using `$and`:

```
db.coll.find({"$and": [                                                                     
            { "fld1": { "$exists": true }}                                              
            , { "fld2": { "$exists": true }}                                            
            , { "fld3": { "$exists": true }}                                            
]})
```

Comment: This type of repetitive listing of `fields + "exists":true` is what I want to avoid, and adding $and to the query does not make it better, just more convoluted. See Blakes Seven's answer as to how to automate building the query using a simple for loop.

Comment: Quite true!   Was simply staying in style with your original post that was using CLI examples.   Programmatic construction of MongoDB queries is the way to go.  It's good to embrace the $and operator as part of that code logic to generically handle all kinds of query expressions.