# Pymongo aggregate: filter by count of fields number (dynamic)

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Let's say I have an aggregation pipeline that for now leads to a collection with documents built like this:

```
{'name': 'Paul',
 'football_position': 'Keeper',
 'basketball_position': 4,...}
```

Obviously not everyone plays every sport so for some documents there would be fields that do not exist. The document regarding them would then be

```
{'name': 'Louis'}
```

What I want to do is to filter people that play at least one sport, inside my aggregation pipeline

I know that this is easy to check for one field with `{'$match': {'football_position': {'$exists': True}}}`, but I want to check if any of these fields exist.

I found an old question a bit similar ([Check for existence of multiple fields in MongoDB document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31136933/check-for-existence-of-multiple-fields-in-mongodb-document)) but it checks for the existence of **all** fields -which, while bothersome, could be attained by the multiplication of multiples `$match` operations. Plus, maybe mongoDB has now a better way to handle this than writing a custom JavaScript function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> maybe mongoDB has now a better way to handle this

Yes, you can now utilise an aggregation operator `$objectToArray` ([SERVER-23310](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-23310)) to turn keys into values. It should be able to count 'dynamic' number of fields. Combining this operator with [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) could be quite useful.

Both operators are available in MongoDB v3.4.4+
Using your documents above as example:

```
db.sports.aggregate([
          { $addFields : 
             { "numFields" : 
               { $size:
                 { $objectToArray:"$$ROOT"}
               }
             }
          }, 
          { $match: 
            { numFields: 
              {$gt:2}
            }
          }
])
```

The aggregation pipeline above, will first add a field called `numFields`. The value would be the size of an array. The array would contain the number of fields in the document. The second stage would filter only for 2 fields and greater (two fields because there's still `_id` field plus `name`).

In [PyMongo](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/), the above aggregation pipeline would look like:

```
cursor = collection.aggregate([
                         {"$addFields":{"numFields":
                                         {"$size":{"$objectToArray":"$$ROOT"}}}}, 
                         {"$match":{"numFields":{"$gt":2}}}
         ])
```

Having said the above, if possible for your use case, I would suggest to reconsider your [data models](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/data-modeling/) for easier access. i.e. Add a new field to keep track of number of sports when a new sport position is inserted/added.

Comment: Excellent ! I was not aware of this new operator but it does the trick :) I'm not sure I can change my data model as the use case is quite different from the example I gave here, but I'll read again this part of the manual and maybe reconsider. Cheers !